# Excel Automatically Grouping

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was referred here from stackoverflow as I was told my question did not require VBA or formulas.

I have a large data set that is in this form, however it is several thousand parts long.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/mN7ZVvt.png]

(Note corporate QTY's are not always the sum of all the stores, as sometimes there is some corporate stock separately).

As of now they are all in that form, with the corporate row at the top of every group.  I would like to do the equivalent of

1. Selecting all the rows between two corporate entries
2. Grouping them

The result would be:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/0WqxNWJ.png]

However is there a way to do this automatically so I don't have to select the rows in a group manually and hit the group button several thousand times?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the **'Subtotal'** button under the Data menu, it will create subgroups for each of the part numbers and calculate a sum (subtotal), count, etc. for each group. You can delete the text below each subgroup if you don't want it in there.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would like the grouping to be at the corporate level.  The corporate data is the highest level or total, however as mentioned in the question, sometimes there is additional corporate stock not included in the stores below it.   So I already have the "summary" lines (the corporate ones), and I want to group all the ones below it.

Answer (score -1):

Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish with the grouping? Are you trying to extract the maximum item quantity's for each store? Normally you could do grouping in pivot tables, or create you own, but I'm just trying to understand what you want to accomplish with this.

This is your initial data, but you would first need to ungroup the grouping by part, and then select how you would want to group.
[pivot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfPeD.png)

Comment: Seconding the use of a Pivot Table. This is a no-brainer.